# 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window

Tags: nativescript

I'm working on my own demo repo to test ThreeJS in NativeScript, and stuck that trivial error I can not figure it out where is the issue - repo: https://github.com/sylwesterdigital/nativescript-threejs-demo

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window
at
init(file: app/home/home-page.ts:206:19)
at myWorld(file: app/home/home-page.ts:190:8)
at canvasLoaded(file: app/home/home-page.ts:141:10)
```

Comment: You should use the renderer from the `nativescript-three` plugin, it's extended from WebGLRenderer to support {N}.

Comment: I'm also having similar kind of problem when I try to preview app on iphone. I'm developing with angular web project. Let me know if you find solution